# Ssh keys transfer to another machine to connect to adhoc server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have generated ssh key in one machine and connected to server (which I needed to connect), now I want to connect to that server using same ssh through other machine. How to do that? Can I copy manually all .ssh files and transfer to new machine?

Comment: What are the source and target clients?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy SSH files. Set the same rights on private key files. Otherwise SSH will notice and not use the keys.

Comment: Do you know the commands to set the same rights on private key files?

Comment: On Linux and Unix use `chmod`

Comment: I need to copy from Windows machine n probably going to use in MACbook....so?